# Managing source for Phonegap cross platform projects in Vault

Tags: cordova, version-control, sourcegear-vault

I'm currently working on my first mobile app with phonegap and wanted to know how Vault users are managing their source for a project that is across multiple platforms.

I've seen articles regarding how to structure it and create sub-modules in Git but haven't seen anything about it in regards to Vault.

I'd like to be able to do something like what is suggested here: [Directory structure for cross-platform phonegap project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273097/directory-structure-for-cross-platform-phonegap-project) I'm just not sure if it is possible in vault.